# searching a 2d array in python - best method + indentation error

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, search, 2d

I have created the following 2d array (list of lists) in Python:

```
#creating a 2d array (3 rows by 7 columns) and populating it with numbers
matrix=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
rows=len(matrix) #finding the max number of rows in the matrix, in this case 3
columns=len(matrix[0]) #finding the max number of columns in each row, 7 in this case
```

I am trying to search for a specific element in the array (say the number 9), and then print "found", if found, and "not found", if not in the array, with the following code:

```
number=int(input("What number are you looking for?"))
for i in range(rows):
      for j in range(columns):
        if matrix[i][j]==number:
          print("Found it!")
          break
else:
  print("not found")
```

The output however, is erroneous:

```
>>What number are you looking for? 9
>>Found it!
>>not found
```

I have two questions: 1. could someone please explain identatation clearly, with reference to this problem and why the second "not found" always is output.
2. Is there a better more efficient way to do this, without the use of numpy

*note, this is not a duplicate, as I have searched the other entries and they don't quite deal with what I am explicitly asking.

repl.it here:
https://repl.it/IcJ3/3

Someone just suggested an answer as below: (I had already tried this)

https://repl.it/IcJ3/5
Note, it doesn't work at all either:

```
number=int(input("What number are you looking for?"))
for i in range(rows):
      for j in range(columns):
        if matrix[i][j]==number:
          print("Found it!")
          break
        else:
          print("not found")
```

Erroneous output, still!

```
What number are you looking for? 9
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
Found it!
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
```

Comment: Your else is not matching the indentation of the if statement.

Comment: for what statement here is else: ?

Comment: I have played around with different positions/identations for the else: ....that's what I need help with. If I knew, I wouldn't be asking! Thanks in advance

Comment: https://repl.it/IcJ3/3

Comment: here is no error in your last edit - you checked every matrix item for "9"

Answer (score 4):

The main problem here is that `break` only exits the innermost loop. So, if an element is found, `break` will skip checking other elements in the same column, but still the outer loop will advance to next row. What you really want is either this:

```
found = False
for row in matrix:
    for element in row:
        if element == number:
            found = True
            break
    if found:
        break
if found:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

(notice the other break)
or, possibly, a more readable solution using a function:

```
def searchfor(matrix, number):
    for row in matrix:
        for element in row:
            if element == number:
                return True
    return False

if searchfor(matrix, number):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

**Edit:** It just occured to me that it is possible to write it without either a flag variable or a function, but it is not a particularly elegant way. Still, for completeness, here you are:

```
for row in matrix:
    for element in row:
        if element == number:
            break
    else:
        continue
    break

if element == number:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

The `continue` statement will execute only if the inner loop **was not** exited by `break`, and it will advance the outer loop to the next row; otherwise the second `break` will end the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be new to Python. In this language, code blocks are identified by the number of indents you have before an instruction. In your case, you have an if statement, but your else is not matching the indentation of that if statement. 
You'd want your code to be something like this -

```
number=int(input("What number are you looking for?"))
flag = False
for i in range(rows):
      for j in range(columns):
        if matrix[i][j]==number:
          print("Found it!")
          flag = True
          break
if flag == False:
  print ("Not found!")
```

Comment: What you have just entered doesn't work at all - it's a previous implementation that I had tried:  Error: What number are you looking for? 9
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
Found it!
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found

Comment: I don't think so. If that `else` matched `if`, "not found" would be printed for every element that is not equal to the one being looked for; that's clearly not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Yes, it's checking for the number and printing not found every time its unequal. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: wait - I wanted it to be fixed without a flag in order to better understand indentation. Or is that impossible? In a language like VB, there would be no need to add an additional layer of complexity (flag) to perform such a simple search

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you require!

```
matrix=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19,20,21]]
x = 93
bool_value = [True if x in mat else False for mat in matrix]
print('Found' if any(bool_value) else 'Not found')
```

**Note:** `any()` returns `True` if atleast one value in the list is true. 
Also in python indentations act as block seperators
For example in c/c++

```
if(condition){
 do a thing
}
else{
do something else
}
```

But in python indentations act as block seperators

```
if (condition):
    do a thing
else:
    do something else
```

where *four whitespaces* or a *tab* acts as block seperators. So if I were to represent the whitespaces with + (This is just for understanding purposes)

```
if (condition):
++++do a thing
else:
++++if (another_condition):
++++++++do_stuff
++++else:
++++++++do_some_other_stuff
print("Exited from nested if/else loops")
```

You get the idea right? And indentation isn't proper in your code that's why every time `not found` is printed.

**EDIT:** As mentioned in comments `[True if x in mat else False for mat in matrix]` can be written as `[x in mat for mat in matrix]` But i will leave it as it is for your understanding since you are new to python.

Comment: This is a good solution, but `True if x in mat else False` is an overly complicated version of much simpler `x in mat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

def search_elm(arr, num):
    elm = False
    for i in range(len(arr)):
      for j in range(len(arr[0])):
        if arr[i][j] == num:
          elm = True
    return elm
```

and you can use it like:

```
if search_elm(matrix, 44):
    print 'Found!'
else:
    print 'Not Found'
```

Comment: Just a shortcut to the word 'element'

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will check **all** elements in the matrix even if the first one was a hit. Inefficient for big matrices.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is if the value exists in the matrix I would go a different route:

```
import itertools

matrix=[
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
     [8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
     [15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
       ]

unique_elements = set(itertools.chain(*matrix))
in_matrix = lambda a, set: a in set

print(in_matrix(3, unique_elements))   #True
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a constant element in matrix you can take advantage of two Map and Lambda together. I've written a simple snippet code here:

```
y = 44
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
if True in map(lambda x: y in x, matrix):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("There is no {} in the given matrix".format(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = 4
ar = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
for i in ar:
    if 4 in i:
        print("found")
        break
else:
    print("not found")
```

this must be the simplest code to find an element in a multi-dimensional array. Also it is not bound with the number of dimensions, unlike other codes here. One can also continue searching for that element if the break statement is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach.

```
    def search(matrix, target):
    r = len(matrix)
    c = len(matrix[0])
    ll = []
    for i in range(0, r*c):
        row = i//c  # division "//" (floor) and division "/" (float)
        col = i % c # remainder
        ll.append(matrix[row][col])

    if(target in ll):
        return True
    else:
        return False


    matrix = [[1, 3, 5, 7], [10, 11, 16, 20], [23, 30, 34, 60]]
    target = 0
    print(search(matrix, target))
```